# Object property value sanitization problem in Angular

Tags: angular, sanitization

I have a class MemberInfo. there is a property which is Photo. Now I would like to create a memberinfo object with property value. the code is below:

```
    let info = new MemberInfo();
    info.MemberId = "101";
    info.MemberName = "Mohammad Nasir Uddin";
    info.Type = "General";
    info.Category = "A";
    info.BloodGroup = "B+";
    info.MobileNo = "012589652357";
    info.Photo = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl("'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/205e460b479e2e5b48aec07710c08d50'");  
    info.ShopNo = "101";
    info.ShopName = "Yellow Computers";
    info.Floor = "First Floor";

this.selectedMember = info;
```

to make safe image url I have sanitized it. But it's shows the compile time error:

> Type 'SafeUrl' is not assignable to type 'string'. info.Photo =
> this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl("'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/205e460b479e2e5b48aec07710c08d50'")

to bind the photo to html I have used the below code:

```
<img [src]="selectedMember.Photo" class="mr-2">
```

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **DomSanitizer** bypassSecurityTrustUrl method returns a **SafeUrl** object from **@angular/platform-browser** namespace.

Now either modify the **Photo** property in **MemberInfo** class to be of **SafeUrl** type or of type **any**.

Thanks.